# Jquery show success image in the current row if checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I have this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div_trattamenti").on('change', '.inpt_chkbox_trattamenti', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
        var id =  $(this).attr('rel');
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);                                                                                                                           // prezzo
        }if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
            var id =  $(this).attr('rel');
            var value = 0;
            alert(value);                                                                                                                           // prezzo
        }

        data_chk = 'id=' + id + '&value=' + value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data_chk,
            cache: false,
            url: "php/aggiorna_chiuso.php",
            success: function(html){
                               var obj = $.parseJSON(html);
                                $.each(obj,function(index, element){
                                    var value2 = element.chiuso;                                // value chiuso
                                    }); // fine .each
                                if(value == 1){
                                    $('.chkmk_img_trattamenti', this).show();
                                }
                                if(value == 0){
                                    $('.chkmk_img_trattamenti', this).hide();
                                }
            },                                                                                  // fine success
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
                console.dir(xhr);
                }                                                                       // fine error
            });                                                                         // fine ajax
    });
});
</script>
```

it works but I am not able to show the image only for the selected row (when user click checkbox).

I tried this but it doesn't work.. :

$('.chkmk_img_trattamenti', this).show();

html code:

```
    $html = '';                         

    $html .= "<table class='class_table'>";

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query_1)){

    $html .= "<tr class='row'>";

    $html .= "<td class='col_1'>";
    $html .= "$row[prestazione]";
    $html .= "</td>";

    $html .= "<td class='col_2'>";
    $html .= "$row[denti]";
    $html .= "</td>";

    $prezzo_2 = number_format($row[prezzo], 0, ',', '.');

    $html .= "<td class='col_1'>";
    $html .= "$prezzo_2";
    $html .= "</td>";       

    $html .= "<td class='col_3'>";
    $html .= "<a href='' class='a_mod_t' rel='$row[id]'><img src='icons/mod.png' border='0' title='modifica trattamento'/></a>";
    $html .= "</td>";

    $html .= "<td class='col_3'>";
    $html .= "<a href='' class='a_mod_prezzo' rel='$row[id]'><img src='icons/euro.png' border='0' title='modifica prezzo'/></a>";
    $html .= "</td>";           

    $html .= "<td class='col_3'>";
    $html .= "<a href='' class='a_delete_t' rel='$row[id]'><img src='icons/delete.png' border='0' title='cancella trattamento'/></a>";
    $html .= "</td>";

    $html .= "<td class='col_4'>";
    $html .= "<div class='chkbox_trattamenti'>";
    $html .= "<form class='form_chkbox_trattamenti'>";
    $html .= "<input type='checkbox' class='inpt_chkbox_trattamenti' value='1' rel='$row[id]'>";
    $html .= "<input class='hidden_id_dottore_chk' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $id; ?>''>";
    $html .= "<input class='hidden_id_paz_chk' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $paziente_id; ?>'>";
    $html .= "<input class='hidden_id_chk' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $trattamento_id; ?>'>";
    $html .= "</form>";
    $html .= "<div class='chkmk_img_trattamenti'>";
    $html .= "<img src='icons/checkmark.png' border='0' title='trattamento chiuso' />";
    $html .= "</div>";
    $html .= "</div>";

    $html .= "</td>";
```

Comment: you just need `$('.chkmk_img_trattamenti').show();`

Comment: I tried but in this way it show the images for all the rows, I need to show that div only in the corresponding row

Comment: can you provide the html as well?

Comment: I copied the code in the answer below

Comment: can you try `$(this).parent().parent().find(".chkmk_img_trattamenti").show()`??

Comment: tried but no luck...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88503/discussion-between-sushil-and-p-davide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the object of the `current` div.

create a variable called `successMsg` and assign it the current object like this

```
var successMsg = $(this);
```

and call it in the success method like this `$(successMsg).parent().parent().find('.chkmk_img_trattamenti').show();`

here's the updated **JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div_trattamenti").on('change', '.inpt_chkbox_trattamenti', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            var id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var value = $(this).val();
            alert(value); // prezzo
        }
        if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")) {
            var id = $(this).attr('rel');
            var value = 0;
            alert(value); // prezzo
        }

        var successMsg = $(this);

        data_chk = 'id=' + id + '&value=' + value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data_chk,
            cache: false,
            url: "php/aggiorna_chiuso.php",
            success: function(html) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(html);
                $.each(obj, function(index, element) {
                    var value2 = element.chiuso; // value chiuso
                }); // fine .each
                if (value == 1) {

                    $(successMsg).parent().parent().find('.chkmk_img_trattamenti').show();

                    //$('.chkmk_img_trattamenti', this).show();
                }
                if (value == 0) {
                    //$('.chkmk_img_trattamenti', this).hide();
                    $(successMsg).parent().parent().find('.chkmk_img_trattamenti').hide();
                }
            }, // fine success
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log(status);
                    console.log(error);
                    console.dir(xhr);
                } // fine error
        }); // fine ajax
    });
});
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $html = '';                         

    $html .= "<table class='class_table'>";

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query_1)){

    $html .= "<tr class='row'>";

    $html .= "<td class='col_1'>";
    $html .= "$row[prestazione]";
    $html .= "</td>";

    $html .= "<td class='col_2'>";
    $html .= "$row[denti]";
    $html .= "</td>";

    $prezzo_2 = number_format($row[prezzo], 0, ',', '.');

    $html .= "<td class='col_1'>";
    $html .= "$prezzo_2";
    $html .= "</td>";       

    $html .= "<td class='col_3'>";
    $html .= "<a href='' class='a_mod_t' rel='$row[id]'><img src='icons/mod.png' border='0' title='modifica trattamento'/></a>";
    $html .= "</td>";

    $html .= "<td class='col_3'>";
    $html .= "<a href='' class='a_mod_prezzo' rel='$row[id]'><img src='icons/euro.png' border='0' title='modifica prezzo'/></a>";
    $html .= "</td>";           

    $html .= "<td class='col_3'>";
    $html .= "<a href='' class='a_delete_t' rel='$row[id]'><img src='icons/delete.png' border='0' title='cancella trattamento'/></a>";
    $html .= "</td>";

    $html .= "<td class='col_4'>";
    $html .= "<div class='chkbox_trattamenti'>";
    $html .= "<form class='form_chkbox_trattamenti'>";
    $html .= "<input type='checkbox' class='inpt_chkbox_trattamenti' value='1' rel='$row[id]'>";
    $html .= "<input class='hidden_id_dottore_chk' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $id; ?>''>";
    $html .= "<input class='hidden_id_paz_chk' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $paziente_id; ?>'>";
    $html .= "<input class='hidden_id_chk' type='hidden' value='<?php echo $trattamento_id; ?>'>";
    $html .= "</form>";
    $html .= "<div class='chkmk_img_trattamenti'>";
    $html .= "<img src='icons/checkmark.png' border='0' title='trattamento chiuso' />";
    $html .= "</div>";
    $html .= "</div>";

    $html .= "</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do hide/show the element :

```
$("#div_trattamenti").on('change', '.inpt_chkbox_trattamenti', function (e) {
       .
       .
       .
      $("#" + this.id).find(" .chkmk_img_trattamenti").show();
       .
       .
       .

});
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work.. then I tried to change the "#" -> "." (as it is a class)

$("." + this.id).find(" .chkmk_img_trattamenti").hide

but it doesn't work..

EDIT: ok I miss a piece...

Comment: I'm not sure how your DOM structure looks like but here's a simple example that might help : http://jsfiddle.net/2rzxu79s/7/